# Authentication in Facebook Canvas App using New Graph API

Tags: javascript, python, django, facebook

I am building a Facebook canvas application that loads in an iframe with Django.  I would like the login process to work similarly to the way Zynga does it.  In this method, if you are not logged in you are redirected to a Facebook login page and then to a permissions request page for the app (without any popups).

As far as I can tell Zynga must be using FBML and just forwarding to URL's that look like:

> http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=[api_key]&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&next=[return_url]

Is there anyway to achieve a similar effect in a python app that loads in an iframe?

There is a method [here](http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2010/05/quick-start-on-new-facebook-php-sdk-iframe-based/) that shows how to achieve the correct redirects using the new php sdk, but I am trying to use the new python SDK which only has the method:

```
def get_user_from_cookie(cookies, app_id, app_secret):
"""
Parses the cookie set by the official Facebook JavaScript SDK.
cookies should be a dictionary-like object mapping cookie names to
cookie values.
...
"""
```

I have some working code that uses the Javascript SDK and the get_user_from_cookie method:

```
<div id="fb-root">
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 FB.init({ apiKey: 'apikey', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // Reload the application in the logged-in state
  window.top.location = 'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/';
 });
</script>
<fb:login-button>Install MyApp</fb:login-button>
```

The problem with this method is that it requires the user to click a button to login and then work through the popup authentication screens. (Note: a popup also occurs if I call FB.login directly)

So... is there a way to use the javascript SDK to redirect to the login page rather than loading it as a popup?

Thanks for any help!
--Eric

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way to use the
>   javascript SDK to redirect to the
>   login page rather than loading it as a
>   popup?

No. The JavaScript SDK will open a new window rather than redirect the current window.

To present the user with a full-screen version of the authorization dialog, you need to redirect them to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={{ application_id }}&redirect_uri={{ redirect_uri }}`. Note that you cannot do this from server-side code, as that would only redirect the iframe and Facebook does not allow it. You'll need an intermediate document that redirects the parent window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
This document redirects the parent window to the authorization
dialog automatically, or falls back to a link if the client does not
support JavaScript.
-->

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.parent.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={{ application_id }}&redirect_uri={{ redirect_uri }}';
    </script>
  </head>

  <body> 
    You must <a target="_top" href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={{ application_id }}&redirect_uri={{ redirect_uri }}">authorize this application</a> in order to proceed.
  </body>
</html>
```

Once the user has authorized your application, he or she will be redirected to the URI you specified in`redirect_uri` and Facebook will populate the GET parameter `signed_request` with all kinds of delicious information (see [the documentation on signed requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas)) that you can use to make requests to Facebook on the user's behalf.

Note that if you plan on saving this signed request (or anything else) to a cookie in a canvas application, you need set compact P3P policies in your headers; otherwise, all versions of Internet Explorer will ignore your cookies.

`P3P: CP="IDC CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"`

I've written a library that makes it really easy to make Facebook canvas applications powered by Django, which takes care of all these things for you. It's called [Fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango), and it's available on github.

Comment: You could redirect them to the authorization page using top.location in javascript

Comment: @BeRecursive: Yes. That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Why redirect to a page that has that code when you code just inject it into the page?

Comment: @BeRecursive: "Injecting it into the page" and "redirecting to a page" are interchangeable as far as the HTTP protocol is concerned. You'd have to make a request either way, and it's cleaner to keep this code in a separate document than facilitate for "injecting it" into every other document.

Comment: Perhaps as far as the actual calls to the server go, but in terms of practice they are obvious totally different. I guess it depends on preference but I wouldn't want to maintain yet another page when I could have a method to inject the correct top.location javascript into any page (given you supply the correct authorization url)

Comment: @BeRecursive: I think you'd be subject to more maintenance by facilitating for completely unrelated code to be injected into every page in your web application, than maintaining a single document that never needs to change. It's also worth considering that not everyone have JavaScript enabled (even in this day and age).

Answer (score 0):

You should use OAuth as described in the documentation about [authentication within Canvas Applications](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas).

The Python SDK you are already using contains an [example](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/oauth/facebookoauth.py) which you should be ready to use almost out of the box.